# fabric.api execute stuck in loop

Tags: python, fabric

Please find the my fabfile.py content below. You may like to change the list of env.hosts to check for yourself.

Kindly note that direct call to chk_* methods would get execute but then also execute against unintended hosts for e.g. chk_kafka also execute against zookeeper group of nodes.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks for bearing with me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
    auto ssh
"""
import os
from fabric.colors import *
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.context_managers import *
from fabric.contrib.console import confirm

env.user = 'centos'
env.password = 'centos'

env.hosts = [
                '10.41.121.78',
                '10.41.121.79',
                '10.41.121.80',
                '10.41.121.81',
                '10.41.121.82',
                '10.41.121.83',
                '10.41.121.84',
                '10.41.121.85'
            ]

clusters = env.hosts

env.hostnames = dict([h, 'gt-%d' % (i + 1)] for i, h in enumerate(clusters))

env.roledefs = {
    'clusters' : clusters,
    'kafka' : clusters[0:5],
    'zookeeper' : clusters[5:8]
}

@task
def status(op=None):
    if op=='zookeeper':
        execute(chk_zk)
    elif op == 'kafka':
        execute(chk_kafka)
    else:
        execute(chk_all)

@roles('zookeeper')
def chk_zk():
    run('jps')

@roles('kafka')
def chk_kafka():
    run('jps')

@roles('clusters')
def chk_all():
    run('jps')
```

Answer (score 1):

adding @runs_once annotation to the method 'status' solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting `env.hosts` explicitly. This is the list of hosts that Fabric will execute tasks on. Usually it would be set via the `-H` (`--hosts`) command line option if you wanted to select specific hosts to execute on. In your setup, it is most sensible to leave `env.hosts` out completely, as you are executing mosts tasks on hosts of specific roles via the `@roles` decorator.

I'm not sure whether your solution works exactly as intended. `@runs_once` will cause the `status` task to only execute once per `fab` run, which effectively means it will run on only one machine, whichever that is, instead of running once for every machine and subsequently triggering the `chk_*` tasks multiple times. I would expect the other tasks to then still be run on all machines mentioned in `env.hosts`, regardless of the roles given via `@roles`.

TL;DR: Remove `env.hosts` and keep `@runs_once` on the `status` task, and you should be fine.